# Cannot get values of some element & attributes when deserializing XML fragment into a C# class

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize XML to class.  I can get some values but not others.

Below is the result in which I can only get the Attribute in the root node.  The attributes and elements of other nodes do not get deserialized.

result:

```
CategoryId  850113
PersonId    null
Name    null
```

Here is the code & xml:

```
void Main()
{
    var xml = GetXml();
    var x = Deserialize(typeof(GetCategoryResponse), xml);
    x.Dump();
}

private object Deserialize(Type typeToDeserialize, string xmlString)
{
    var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
    var xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = xdoc.Root.Name.LocalName, IsNullable = false };

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);
    var mem = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeToDeserialize, xRoot);
    return ser.Deserialize(mem);
}

public class GetCategoryResponse
{
   [XmlAttribute("cat")]
   public string CategoryId { get;set; }

   [XmlAttribute("pid")]
   public string PersonId { get; set; }

   [XmlElementAttribute("pname")]
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public string GetXml()
{
    return @"<response cat=""850113"" abID=""var.can.do"" uid=""8a561340-fab0-4389-a01d-e13e103b3204"">
    <test val=""cat"">
        <messsage>There is a cat in the tree on my knee.</messsage>
    </test>
    <person pid=""4433"">
    <pname>Cherry Pop</pname>
    </person>
    </response>";
```

}

I tried using XSD but the class it generates is absolutely horrible - and doesn't work properly either.  While i can accomplish this manually I want the Deserialize method above to work generically with any class passed in (providing it has proper attributes for mapping to the xml fragment).

Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your XML and your Class, you are saying PID should be an attribute, the XML does not have PID as an attribute so naturally the Deserializer fails to find it.
Similarly your class says pName will be an element, and it looks for pName under the root element but your XML has pName nested under another element.

EDIT:
Once you take care of the above you can pass any class to it which has proper attributes matching data type and it should work.

Links:

[XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Role of Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, i do not follow.  PID is an attribute of the person node also, how do I get it to look for pName element when its NOT in the root?  Is that an attribute (or xpath type thing) setting or something?  Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Comment: It will not look for PID in the Person Node, it will look for it in the response node. I think you need to understand how XML Serialization works and how it can be controlled through attributes. I have added links for the MSDN resources in my post above. Also, try to Serialize a class and go through the XML created by the Serializer, that will also help you understand it.